# Moving the last element of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, move, move-semantics

What is the most efficient way to obtain the last (heavy) element from a vector and remove it, and make as few copies as possible?
Is it

```
template <typaname T>
T moveLastElement (std::vector<T>& vec) {
    T t = std::move(vec.back());
    vec.pop_back();
    return t;
}
```

Comment: This looks fine. Though maybe you should add another `std::move` in the return statement just in case NRVO doesn't kick in.

Comment: @ David G   I tried using `return std::move(t);` but GCC warned "moving a local object in a return statement prevents copy elision", which sounds to me like : don't do that.

Comment: That sounds like your compiler uses NRVO, so you're free to omit the extra move.

Comment: @DavidG Using `std::move` will prevent NRVO from being applied. If you add it "just in case" NRVO is not available, you are giving up NRVO altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're talking about copy elision, and specifically NVRO, and I'm assuming @presto that you're compiling for (at minimum) C++17, there's an interesting edge case.

Suppose you have a function like this:

```
heavy_object fox_this_compiler ()
{
    heavy_object h1;
    heavy_object h2;

    return (some_condition_that_cant_be_evaluated_at_compile_time) ? h1 : h2;
}
```

Now the compiler's in a quandry, because it can't construct *both* `h1` *and* `h2` at the call site, and that's what NVRO depends on.  So (and I just ran a quick test), it returns a copy (and one of you language lawyers can tell me why).

So this is a case where explicitly moving from the object you're returning is worthwhile, as you can see in the:

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2ZcL20rOEUbYhdGv)

I'm not sure if there's some kind of type trait to let you know if you need to do this in any particular instance, but if there is I don't know about it.

---

**Edit:** turns out there is a way.  Just stick the call to `std::move` in there and if you don't need it, gcc will warn you (but if you do, it won't).  Nifty.  But, sadly, it won't warn you when you do need it and you fail to put it in.

Comment: why not: `heavy_object res = std::move((some_condition_that_cant_be_evaluated_at_compile_time) ? h1 : h2);` return res;?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If you look behind the link, that is exactly what you will see (more or less).  What you have and what I have are equivalent. [ edit ] actually, no.  I believe that what you are proposing will do a move and then a copy.  Try it.

Comment: It will do a move and copy elision. But a non-madatory one. So I guess I didn't gain anything for the non-NVRO case.

Comment: second attempt: `return heavy_object((cond) ? h1 : h2);` This will invoke the move constructor (fallback to copy) and mandatory copy elision.

Comment: In the original both h1 and h2 qualify for NVRO. So both copy/move and elision would be legal for the compiler. Could the compiler do both? Assume the condition is true so NVRO `h1` and if the condition is false then copy/move `h1 = h2`. Would that be legal?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Why all this speculation?  Just follow the link, take a look at what I did, and then experiment for yourself.

Comment: That link will show me what one compiler does. Not what is legal.

Comment: @OP asked about efficiency, not what is legal.  When returning by value, pretty much anything is legal, if it compiles.  I've had enough of this now.

Comment: I was just speculating about your corner case. Not what OP initially asked.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Sure, but worth mentioning all the same.  There's no compiler warning if you write code like this and it would (obviously) impact efficiency so I thought I'd toss it in.